# Rotate and resize rectangle drawn in canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-shape

In my `Android` application I have drawn rectangle in canvas, how can I rotate rectangle and resize the rectangle on touch events ?

```
canvas.drawRect(300,300,500,500,paint);
```

This code is used to draw the rectangle.

Comment: Explain better please!

Comment: i want to draw shapes in android,so i used canvas and drawn rectangle first,then i need to rotate the rectangle and resize the rectangle By touching the rectangle (gesture detection).How can i do that

Comment: use the gesture or onclick and the code in the answer of @radjan ks

Answer (score 0):

You can do using below

```
canvas.save(); // saving current canvas
```

**resize**

```
rect.set(x,y,newWidth, newHeight);
```

**rotate**

```
canvas.rotate(45);
```

**Apply changes**

```
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
canvas.restore();
```